# Keeping Python Interpreter always on [Windows]

Tags: python, windows, interpreter

I run several custom python scripts on my Windows machine all the time. I also use batch files to link to these python scripts so I can easily control them from Run/Command Prompt:

(As an example I have a command which converts one file to another(like html to tex) using the corresponding available modules, so I don't need to remember them. Like the command `Directory> python converter.py -C:/{Path to File} -tex -pdf` converts the tex file to the pdf without me intervening further and gives a message box at the end. I also have a batch file(named pizza.bat all it does is give a command to run this python file by going to its directory and basically taking care of all the long steps I want to avoid) in system 32 so I can run this directly from the windows run without going to the directory `pizza -C:{File Path} -tex -pdf`. Obviously there are heavy modules that need to be imported. I need to know if there is a way I can import these modules and keep the python interpreter always running. Basically my python interpreter never shuts down. This should speed up my tasks.
The reason I gave an entire explanation about what I do is basically because if this makes any difference and if yes how to deal it.

Any advice is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Create a service, or run a script as a background task using the scheduler. Either way, the service/task can use a named pipe or socket to accept requests and perform operations on behalf of clients.

Comment: The scripts for the clients shouldn't need a batch file wrapper if .py files are associated with py.exe or python.exe and ".PY" is in the `PATHEXT` environment variable.

Comment: @ErykSun agreed. But that is not what majorly is ticking me 
Also I tried the background scheduler, though it's a tad bit faster, it still loads all the modules and stuff. Effectively the time taken remains the same.

Comment: The point was to split it up into a client/server architecture. The server gets executed once and only once as a background service/task. Client scripts would just be a thin UI and proxy, with all of the heavy work that relies on other packages implemented in the server process.